# How should I grow calla lilies?

Tags: houseplants, flowers, lily

I have no experience in gardening. I have a pot of Calla lilies but I have no idea how to take care of it. It came with a label that suggests keeping it at a sunny place. But apart from that, I don't know anything else. How often should I water it? How big and deep should the pot be? When should I transfer it to a bigger pot? Is there anything else I should know?

Answer (score 5):

Here is some basic info on how to keep your plant healthy:

- Keep the soil moist, but not wet. Test this with your finger. If the potting mix is dry more than 1/2" deep, water thoroughly until water drains from the bottom of the pot.
- Transfer to a larger pot if the plant becomes rootbound. Test this by removing from the pot, and looking at the root-ball. If it looks like a mass of circling roots, and you can't see much soil, it's time to repot. Use a pot one size larger, and add high quality organic potting mix as required.
- Fertilize once every other week with a balanced, soluble fertilizer with the watering. This promotes healthy growth and flowering.
- Locate in a bright location out of direct sun. They don't like direct sun, as it can burn the leaves.
- Calla lilies overheat easily. don't place them in a location that gets over 75 degrees F. on a regular basis, or they won't thrive.